# Project facet Java version 1.8 is not supported, Tomcat 9, Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am currently having an issue with setting up a Tomcat server to run a Java 8 servlet. I've included snippets of the settings that are relevant to the issue. As you can see, I have jdk-1.8 installed and bound to the project build path. I have spent hours trying to figure out why Eclipse keeps saying Java 1.8 is not supported by Tomcat 9. If you look in at the project facets runtimes, you'll see that the server shows jre-1.7 even though I have set the path to the jre-1.8. I'm convinced this is where the issue is, but I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried setting the same Tomcat server up on another machine with no problems so I'm confused as to why it isn't working on this one. The major difference between the two is that the one that works properly shows jre-1.8 in the runtimes.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen on Windows 10

[image: Run on Server]

[image: Edit Server Runtime Environment]

[image: Project Facets]

[image: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml]

[image: pom.xml snippet]

Comment: Try with something newer than the Oxygen release. It's two years old at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @nitind. I ended up reinstalling Eclipse Oxygen. I was browsing through the add or remove programs window and noticed I still had Java 1.7 so I decided to uninstall that then reinstall the Eclipse version I've been using. It works! The runtimes are showing jre-1.8 now. So all of that headache could have been solved so easily.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I had Java 1.7 still installed in my machine (Java 1.8 was there too) so I went ahead and uninstalled the older version and then I reinstalled Eclipse Oxygen. Everything works now. The runtimes are showing jre-1.8. I have not a single clue exactly why it wasn't working before; but if you have this same issue, try giving this a shot.